# Display a modal from Material UI dropdown selection

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, menuitem

The goal is to open a delete option modal from a material ui dropdown menu.

The first step towards that is understanding how to simply select an item from a dropdown, and then trigger some form of action (opening the modal) depending on which item is selected.

The [material UI docs](https://mui.com/components/menus/) all seem to offer samples in which `onClick` simply handles the closing of the menu.  It seems there are rare examples of selecting something from a dropdown and then opening/doing things from there?

I'm having trouble seeing where I would insert the logic/event handling to handle 'if the user selects option x, open modal regarding option x' within the context of a material ui menu.

Here's my code to show the rabbit hole I'm down currently:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import { useState } from 'react'
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

interface IProps extends Omit<unknown, 'children'> {
    children: any;
    options: string[];
}

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;

const DropdownMenu = ({ children, options }: IProps) => {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const handleChange = (event: any) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
        console.log(value)
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <IconButton
                aria-label="more"
                id="long-button"
                aria-controls="long-menu"
                aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                {children}
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
                id="long-menu"
                MenuListProps={{
                    'aria-labelledby': 'long-button'
                }}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                PaperProps={{
                    style: {
                        maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5,
                        width: '20ch'
                    }
                }}
            >
                <Select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                    {options.map(option => (
                        <MenuItem key={option} onClick={handleClose} >
                            {option}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DropdownMenu;
```

How would I use the dropdown to trigger the invocation of a Modal component based on a string value?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right then this should be the solution. simply assign a ref to the triggering element (in this case it's the IconButton). then you can open the menu via setting the open state. BTW why should the button render children?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import { FC, useState } from 'react';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

type DropdownMenuProps = {
    options: string[];
};

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;

const DropdownMenu: FC<DropdownMenuProps> = ({ children, options }) => {
    const anchorEl = React.useRef<null | HTMLButtonElement>(null);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    const handleChange: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement> = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        setValue(value);
        if (value === 'the value you want to trigger the menu') {
            setOpen(true);
        }
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <IconButton
                aria-label="more"
                id="long-button"
                aria-controls="long-menu"
                aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleClick}>
                {children}
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
                id="long-menu"
                MenuListProps={{
                    'aria-labelledby': 'long-button',
                }}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                PaperProps={{
                    style: {
                        maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5,
                        width: '20ch',
                    },
                }}>
                <Select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                    {options.map((option) => (
                        <MenuItem key={option} onClick={handleClose}>
                            {option}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DropdownMenu;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rainer.  I should have indicated that I'm using typescript.  I'll re-ask elsewhere to clarify, and drop the link here.

Comment: Rainier if you care to continue down the rabbit hole I've attempted to clean up the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69471494/open-a-modal-or-dialogue-from-a-dropdown-asking-the-user-if-they-would-like-to)

Comment: My code is written in typescript. So I don't understand what You mean.

Comment: Sorry about that Rainer - my bad!  When I tried running the code you suggested, I still had a few errors, but those were likely due to the linters that apply to the repo I'm working on, not a typescript issue from your code.   Thank you for your help!